# Each frame calculation vs pre-rendered bitmaps

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization

1. We create some MovieClips and use Motion Tween to animate them.
2. We create some MovieClips and use Motion Tween to animate them, then render all frames as .png and create MovieClips with all those rendered .pngs.

I guess second way take less time, because you skip tween calculation step. Which way of animation is more proper/fast?

Comment: The first one. You could try it and see what works better in your situation?

Comment: Which way is "faster/better" generally results in opinionated responses that are only true given a particular scenario.  There is generally some way to make a memory/CPU trade off as you're eluding to (known as memoization), however this does not always result in "faster" depending on where you need it to be "faster".  Take for example Device A has 2GB of RAM and a 1GHz proc, Device B has 256MB of RAM and a 4GHz proc, the use of memory over CPU in device B is better, the opposite is true for device A. (down voted for this reason)

Comment: (3) create Sprite sheets, then cut them up and store each in memory as a bmp, or 
(4) Tween each one time, then take a "snapshot" at each position, store the snapshots, and use them for the animation from there on out
;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's of course the first one. Maybe your intention is good but it wouldn't pay off in the long term and it's also micro-optimization and it's considered bad. It doesn't make the code readable and it can slow down your loading time. In general calculation is also faster because you don't need to change the whole screen. So it really depends if the second version uses for example delta packing for the animation.